# Windows: get processes exec path on non-admin user

Tags: windows, winapi, process

This is for Windows (XP, 7, or 8) related question.

Is it possible to get processes exec path without admin rights?

If possible, can you advice?

**UPDATE:**

**Sample working code:**

```
#RequireAdmin
#include <array.au3>

Dim $proc[1][3]
Dim $i = 0

$WMI = ObjGet("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2")
$result = $WMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process", "WQL",0x10 + 0x20)

If IsObj($result) Then
   For $res In $result
      $Proc[UBound($proc)-1][0] = $res.Name
      $Proc[UBound($proc)-1][1] = $res.Handle
      $Proc[UBound($proc)-1][2] = $res.ExecutablePath
      ReDim $proc[UBound($proc) + 1][3]
   Next
   ReDim $proc[UBound($proc) - 1][3]
Else
   Msgbox(0,'Result','No result found')
Endif

_ArrayDisplay($Proc,'Process List')][1]
```

**Output:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0guuG.png]

Comment: Please provide an example of what you tried. Is there an API function you're having a problem with?

Comment: Are you asking how to get an module filename from something? From what? A PID? Please expand the question with details.

Comment: Who down voted knows nothing. Better get out of the topic instead of down voting the question.

Comment: @MarCejas: you got downvoted (not by me) because of the quality of the question. More care in asking questions will avoid this.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a process ID, use `OpenProcess()` to get a `HANDLE` to the process, then use [`GetProcessImageFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`QueryFullProcessImageName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the filename of the process.

If you need the command-line parameters that were passed to the process, that is much harder to do.  You have to use [`NtQueryInformationProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the address of the process's [`PEB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)structure and then use [`ReadProcessMemory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to read the contents of the PEB's `ProcessParameters.CommandLine` member, which is a [`UNICODE_STRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.  Note that this will fail if you try to access processes that belong to other user accounts, or running with higher privileges, unless your process has the `SeDebugPrivilege` privilege, such as by enabling it with [`AdjustTokenPrivileges()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: You have to use the API functions I mentioned, you won't be able to get the process paths from WMI. Except that you cannot open Process 0 with `OpenProcess()` (not even Task Manager can display that path). `OpenProcess()` works for process 4, but querying the path fails. You can get the path for `smss.exe` if your app is running as an admin, though.

Comment: My current solution is OK but client is wanting non-admin to see process paths too. So, are you really sure that this is impossible?